# How to focus on first edittext when it's clicked and scroll view focus down

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, cursor

On my authorization page I have three edittext and when I click first one I make like that My screen scrolling down to show another edittext and button under first edittext, but here I found next problem. When I click first edittext my cursor goes to last edittext and I haven't any idea how to fix it please help.

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kiz6U.png)

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxKwV.png)